# ASP.NET - Datagrid with Display, Edit, Delete and Sort functionalities

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

Would you please let me know a reference document or web reference for the following:

Datagrid with Displaying (along with paging), Editing, Deleting and Sorting of records in an ASP.NET application

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of tutorials on getting to know the basics for the gridview control.  Most of what you ask are settings on the gridview to have it sort, page and allow editing/deleting.

http://quickstarts.asp.net/quickstartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/gridview.aspx

http://aspnet101.com/aspnet101/tutorials.aspx?id=51

I am assuming you meant the gridview control BUT if you are needing it for the old datagrid control then here's a nice link for that:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210608183626/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/040502-1.aspx